# YO .net core 2.x demo project with react/redux?

Tags: yeoman-generator

This is a "Veracity Platform" question - which I guess has a fairly small audience.

I'm using the veracity platform's application generator (based on Yeoman) to generate a sample application for .net core 2.x, using node.js.

yo @veracity/veracity:netcore-webapp

This creates a good basic .net core 2.x MVC project. Is there a way to further specify that I want to additionally include the "React/Redux" project template, like I would when creating a project in Visual Studio?  That way the client app and the front-end webpack stack get started for me, which is nice.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have these configurations included in the generator yet. Uservoice will be added to Developer.veracity.com soon, but for now you may forward such feature requests also in the github project of the generator. Open an issue, and I will see when we can get it in to the backlog.

https://github.com/veracity/generator-veracity

Brede Børhaug - Manager Veracity for Developers

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.